# Why can't we just immediately Fourier Transform the dirac comb? Why do we need to define it's Fourier Series first?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, dirac-delta, periodic-functions

I feel like this is a question with an easy answer but I cannot find an explanation. In the connection between the Fourier Series and the Fourier transform, it is shown that any periodic function is the convolution of a dirac comb (impulse train) with the function that is desired. However, in order to show the results, you need to know the Fourier Transform of the Dirac Comb, but every derivation I found calculates the fourier series *first*. I tried to run the calculation myself but I get stuck.

Here is my attempted solution:

$\mathcal{F}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = \infty} \delta(t-nT)) =$

$\sum_i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-nT)e^{-i2\pi f' t} dt=$

$\sum \int\int e^{2\pi i f(t-nT)}e^{-i2\pi f' t} dt df $

$= \sum \int \delta(f-f')e^{-i2\pi nTf'}df = \sum e^{-i2\pi f' nT}$

What am I doing wrong? Is this even valid?

Comment: The infinite sum of complex exponentials is not something that makes sense (outside of being a Fourier series) or is useful directly since it doesn't tell us what it looks like. But it is still a valid representation of the FT of the comb.

Comment: You messed up with $f$ and $f'$. The point is that $\sum_n e^{2i\pi nx}$ converges only in the sense of distributions, and it is not obvious at all that the limit is $\sum_n \delta(x-n)$.

Comment: Reuns, could you elaborate on what you mean by this convergence? I'm very weak on my knowledge of distributions to be honest.

Comment: @cheekylittleduck See https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/12/21/distributions/